# excelTable from excelR package R programming is not showing out put

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript, jexcelapi, excelr

`excelTable()` from ExcelR package is showing no output in the Viewer Pane. I have updated all the dependent packages. what could be the problem?

```
data = data.frame(Model = c('Mazda', 'Pegeout', 'Honda Fit', 'Honda CRV'),
                   Date=c('2006-01-01', '2005-01-01','2004-01-01', '2003-01-01' ),
                   Availability = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))

columns = data.frame(title=c('Model', 'Date', 'Availability'),
                      width= c(300, 300, 300),
                      type=c('text', 'calendar', 'checkbox')) 

excelTable(data=data, columns = columns)
```

[image]
    `sessionInfo()`
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTm8.png) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTm8.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTm8.png) jsonlite_1.6      htmlwidgets_1.5.1 excelR_0.3.1      covr_3.3.2        testthat_2.1.1    shiny_1.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTm8.png) Rcpp_1.0.0       pillar_1.3.1     compiler_3.5.1   later_1.0.0      plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.5.1      digest_0.6.18    tibble_2.0.1     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.4.1      Matrix_1.2-14
[14] rex_1.1.2        rstudioapi_0.9.0 yaml_2.2.0       fastmap_1.0.1    dplyr_0.8.0.1    grid_3.5.1       tidyselect_0.2.5 glue_1.3.0       R6_2.4.0         ggplot2_3.1.0    purrr_0.3.1      magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0
[27] promises_1.1.0   htmltools_0.4.0  assertthat_0.2.0 mime_0.6         colorspace_1.4-0 xtable_1.8-3     httpuv_1.5.2     bs4Dash_0.3.0    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.3.4

> 

Comment: Are you running the code within a shiny? That package seems to be designed for use within a shiny (e.g. `excelOutput` and `renderExcel` create shiny functions)

Comment: I believe the excelTable function works without shiny framework.

Comment: To me your code's working with R 3.6.1 and excelR 0.3.1, which version of R and excelR are you running (despite I suppose it could not be the problem)?

Comment: I have added the sessionInfo(). Please check

Answer (score 3):

After discussing this issue with the package developer, I found that the version of the rstudio is the main cause of the problem of not viewing the output. The code is running successfully on the versions 1.2.5019 and 1.2.1322 and not in the older versions like 1.1.456. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using html_notebook output type. That output type will always have inline output. May be try to choose a different R markdown document type. Go to File and click 'New' then click 'R Markdown' and then 'Document'. That should open an html_document output type, which will follow your preferences for inline output.

Comment: If that still doesn't work try this: 

Click on 'gear button' in the editor toolbar
Click 'Chunk Output in Console' from the list.

Comment: I don't want to use Rmarkdown or Shiny. I just want to view the output in the viewer pane by running a simple Rscript.